# [Unity][Firebase] Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex: Error Building Player

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am trying to add Firebase Analytics and Firebase Messaging in my Unity App.
I am using Latest official package for Firebase and Unity 2017.4.0f1

After importing Firebase when I try to make a build it fails with the following error

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
```

I have search every where but I am not able to find a solution, people have solved this on Android Studio but I am not able to solve on on Unity. I am not sure how to fix it. 
Please help, it will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same question, but with unity 5.6.6.
I have tried create custom mainTemplate.gradle and add this code to "andrond" section and "buildscript" section

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

But it's not helps.

I have found solution! Little dirty, but works.

1) I have used tool JarCheck http://mindprod.com/products1.html#JARCHECK
and found, what problem in com.google.auto.value.auto-value-annotations-1.6.jar (it built for java 1.8), all other libs is 1.7. 
This jar added into build by PlayServicesResolver for Firebase.

2) Disable "Auto resolution" in Assets->Play Service Resolver->Android resolver->settings.

3) Delete com.google.auto.value.auto-value-annotations-1.6.jar from "Assets\Plugins\Android\". Firebase looks working ok without this lib.

But now this should be deleted manually after every manual resolution of GP.

Comment: well this solution is good but not applicable where you need resolver to run frequently :) But thanks Answer accepted. How can I use the above tool on MAC? I have downloaded it but not able to run it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case..
I updated firebase from 5.3 to 5.5 and the same problem occurred with unity 5.6.5f1

Check this..
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/321

I updated Google play game service plugin from 0.9.5 to 0.9.62
and solved